# I need to extract one varying number from a string in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract one number from a string in excel using VBA

An example of the string would be:

58.00 km  Travel Reimbursement 2001 - 3500cc Petrol: 51.62 @ Travel Reimbursement
Station - Yellow
 Comment:  OT duties at place one from place two.

The number I need to extract is the amount paid which is 51.62, this number always varies but is always between : and @.

All help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Split on `@` and take the first element from the array, then split that on `:` and take the second element from that array.

Comment: Alternatively, use `InStr` to find the positions of your start and end characters, use `Mid` to extract the characters in between those 2 positions.

Comment: =mid(A1,find(A1,”:”,1)+1,find(A1,”:”,1)-2) but test as +1 and -2 may need changing or wrap the expression with trim()

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbReimbursement()
 Dim sExpenses As String
 Dim iColonPos As Integer
 Dim iAtPos As Integer
 Dim sPrice As String
 sExpenses = "58.00 km Travel Reimbursement 2001 - 3500cc Petrol: 51.62 @ Travel Reimbursement"
 iColonPos = InStr(1, sExpenses, ":")
 iAtPos = InStr(1, sExpenses, "@")
 sPrice = Trim(Mid(sExpenses, iColonPos + 1, iAtPos - iColonPos - 1))
 MsgBox sPrice
End Sub
```